# Vector of Class-Object pointers: How to get value at pointer address? C++ and SDL_Rect

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, sdl, stdvector

I've got a vector of class-object pointers. I declare the vector in main..:

```
std::vector<Class1*> vector1;
vector1.push_back(&object1);
vector1.push_back(&object2);
```

The below error occurs. This is just the simplest variant of trying to access data contained within the class pointed to by the vector.

Ex:

Main.cpp:

```
std::cout << vector1[0]->rect->w << std::endl;
```

Class1.h

```
SDL_Rect rect{100, 100, 50, 50};
```

The above results in a red underline of the word 'Vector1' with the error "Expression must have a valid pointer type".

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that I'm trying to get to a **SDL_Rect** contained within the Class-Objects pointed to by the vector... Not sure how/if that changes anything.
I'll provide more complete code when I'm off work.

The code I've provided works if I simply specify a variable of a normal type such an int (where 'age' below is an int):

```
 std::cout << vector1[0]->age << std::endl;
```

But since I'm specifying an SDL_Rect in the example from Main.cpp I get the error I mentioned. Anyone know what the peculiarity is?

Comment: `vector1[i]` yields a pointer like any other. Just use `->` like you would for a regular `Class1*`. Edit : Actually, I'm just assuming. Your function isn't actually legal c++ so it's not possible to say with certainty at this point.

Comment: `exampleFunction(vector1, int offset 5)` this is invalid C++ code, please [edit] and clarify

Comment: instead of vector1[i].width += offset; do vector1[i]->width += offset;

Comment: `exampleFunction(vector1, offset){`: still invalid C++

Comment: Please read [mcve] for guidelines on providing complete and helpful examples. Please only share real code that you've tried yourself.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it red-underlines vector1 and states 'expression must have a valid pointer type' when I try to do vector1[0]->width.

Comment: @Arianax Then I don't know what the problem is. Please post a MCVE (see my previous comment for a link) and then we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < vector1.size(); i++)
{
    vector1[i]->width += offset;
}
```

Dereference the pointer with `->` as you normally would.